# How to merge items in a clojure list by types?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to merge items within a Clojure list by the data type of items.

I tried using `conj`, `merge`, `into` to merge items. But they seem to work perfectly when the list items have the same data types.

```clj
(def args '({:a 1} "Heading"))
(def args2 ({:b 2}))
(conj args args2)
```

The output I get is `({:b 2} {:a 1} "Heading")`. Instead I would like to achieve `({:b 2 :a 1} "Heading")`.

Comment: What if both inputs contain a string?

Comment: For my specific case it multiple strings are there they are the part of the list. Final result can look like `({:b 2 :a 1} "Heading 1" "Heading 2")`. But it would be great if I could specify if I want to concat them or not.

Answer (score 6):

It is a little bit complicated, but since you asked for flexibility, there you go:

```
(defmulti conjoin first)

(defmethod conjoin :default [[k v]] v)
(defmethod conjoin (class {}) [[k v]] [(apply merge v)])
(defmethod conjoin (class []) [[k v]] [(vec (apply concat v))])

(let [a '({:a 1} "Heading" [a])
      b '({:b 2} "Fake" [b])]
    (->> (concat a b)
         (group-by class)
         (mapcat conjoin)))
=> ({:a 1, :b 2} "Heading" "Fake" [a b])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems really clean and adaptable for future use cases. Realized it more after porting it for my own use case.

Comment: Though this works perfectly in case of Clojure. But when I start using it in ClojureScript I get the error `Use of undeclared Var ad.base.typography/class`. I modified the `class` method to `type` and it worked like a breeze.